# Mozilla - wrong right fixed position of element

Tags: html, firefox, markup

I have contacts block at the right top corner. It shows only when scrollTop() > 100.

In Mozilla it slides down in wrong right position.

Just scroll down so block is appear and hover the text in Mozilla - it will jump to the proper right value. Then if you scroll back to top - it will jump to wrong position and then slides up.

http://jsfiddle.net/7nfDd/3/

```
Maybe I just do something wrong? Any help will be appreciated.
```

Firefox 20.0.1

Comment: Looks fine to me. It does the same as in Chrome and IE9. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: once again, when it slides down, it touches scroll bar, bust must be in 10px to the left. When you hover text in it, it jumps to right:10px from what it looks like right:1px or 2px

Comment: You're right, that is strange. It only happens when the `span:hover` has a `text-shadow`.

Comment: Yeap, but. Look closely, without span:hover it still appear in wrong position. Compare it with Chrome and you'll see